# How do i put multiple images(ImageView) in a ScrollView?

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview, scrollview

i want to put multiple images and scroll down and see them all. I tried to put a ScrollView and inside a ImageView but i dont know if i need to put a layout. I searched tutorials but i didnt found what i needed.

Comment: Please be more descriptive of the use case you're trying to implement.  When you say multiple images, are you referring to a fixed number of images? Otherwise you could try implementing a GridView that may have a CardView inside where you can put your images etc.  Be mindful of memory usage when displaying images.  Cheers

Comment: I want to put images and a button under each one to share the image that the user want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's clearly not how `ScrollView`s work. `ScrollView` is a `ViewGroup`, so you have to put it *outside* the view that you want to scroll.

Also, there can only be one view as the direct child of scroll view. So you cannot do this:

```
<ScrollView>
    <ImageView>
    <ImageView>
    <ImageView>
</ScrollView>
```

Actually, you should put the images in a `LinearLayout`, and put the `LinearLayout` in the scroll view.

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
        <ImageView>
        <ImageView>
        <ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Note: the attributes are omitted because I'm lazy :P**

EDIT:

If you want to scroll down, just set the `orientation` attribute to `"vertical"`.

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        other attributes.../>
            image views here...
    </LinearLayout
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Ok i tried and it worked, but i cant go down i can only use the screen space and i want to go down, how can i do that?

Comment: @Avlas299 So you want to scroll down? Just set the `orientation` attribute of the `LinearLayout` to `"vertical"`. I'll edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Android documentation for CardViews http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

You can put an image within each CardView element and a sharebutton below the image.  As I previously said, good memory management is a must when working with images and the RecyclerView will work just well.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you, it helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

**Try this method**

```
<ScrollView>
<LinearLayout>
    <ImageView>
    <ImageView>
    <ImageView>
    <ImageView>
    <ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```